# Wordpress Unable to displaying custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to create custom posts, Admin site work well but posts are not displayed on client side 
Tutorial I followed

1. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes--wp-27645
2. https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin

Both tutorial does not work for me.

I am **able** to create new custom posts (Review type (music, movie))
When I Click on View post button it take me to 
http://localhost/test001/music_review/mama-love/
While page says

> "Oops! That page can’t be found."

However If I search "Mama Love" result shows an entry for it but when clicked, it again take me to the above link with same error.
This has worked for me only once. I tried both tutorials separately with new Worpress site(So they both are not conflicting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've registered a custom post type you need to flush your rewrite rules.

1. In the WordPress admin to go Settings -> Permalinks
2. Press "Save Changes"

Comment: You are hero Nathan, How could I was not able to find out from Google, may be I was not looking for the right terms. Thank you so much :)